# If one condition is met by group by, filter it

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am trying to filter from the following table all the ids which have at least one `status = C`. If it has C status filter it from my existing table

This is an example of my hole dataset (example to illustrate my problem)

```
    id  | status
 -------------
   4567 | B
   4567 | A
     27 | A
     27 | A
     27 | C
      9 | C
      9 | B
```

Expected result

```
    id  | status
 -------------
   4567 | B
   4567 | A
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
SELECT id,status FROM TABLE T 
   WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT id FROM TABLE T1 WHERE status ='C' )
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `not exists`:

```
select t.*
from t
where not exists (select 1 from t t2 where t2.id = t.id and t2.status = 'C');
```